# How to stop the LocalNotificationSound when application is opening from Device Locking screen

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

In my application iam using UILocalNotifications, and for that notification iam setting 30 sec audio file.

- Notification fired if device is UnLock state and my app is in background mode then if i click on notification bar then my app is open and notification sound is stopping. This scanario is fine.
- Notification fired if device is locke state and my app is in background mode then if i drag the notification then my app is open and notification sound is not stopping. In this scanario notification sound is continuesly playing upto 30 sec.

I need to stop the notification sound when app is open.
Please help me for implementing this functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, since the sound is played by iOS and not your app. Thus you have no control over it.

Comment: if i click on volume buttons then the sound is stopping,How?

Comment: Because again that is iOS handling the sound not your app. You try and change the volume or cancel all notifications, but I've not been able to make the sound stop.

Comment: ya,even i try with changing the volume of MediaPlayer, No use. and also i cancelled all notifications.

Comment: My guess is that it is not possible, you might want to submit a bug report with apple so that they can fix it in an upcoming release of iOS.